# How to read a spreadsheet with WSH?

Tags: excel, com, spreadsheet, wsh, jscript

I need to read some cell values from a .xls file using JScript under WSH.

Is there any COM object or anything that I can use to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is a COM component for this. Its progId is "Excel.Application" and you use it like this:

```
var XLS = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application") ;
XLS.Workbooks.open(xlsFile) ;
var cellValue = XLS.Cells(row,col).Value ;
```

That's it. As simple as that. The variable `cellValue` now holds the value in the cell (`row`,`col`).
And if that's not good enough, `xlsFile` may be the path to a file or a URL (yes, a URL!, great isn't it).

Answer (score 1):

You could use ADO to read the values...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx

Comment: note: I think the examples there are in VBScript... but you could just as easily use jscript you just need to get your casing correct...

Answer (score 0):

%windir%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe ExcelSheetName.vbs

ExcelSheetName.vbs:

```
Const ArrSize = 100

Dim ArrSheetName()

ReDim ArrSheetName(ArrSize)

IndexArr = 0



Dim ExcelFileName

ExcelFileName = "D:\1\ExcelSrc.xls"


Dim ADOCatalog, ADOTable, ADODBConnection

Set ADOCatalog      = Createobject("ADOX.Catalog")

Set ADOTable        = Createobject("ADOX.Table")

Set ADODBConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


Dim strConnString, strSheetName

strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & ExcelFileName & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"


ADODBConnection.Open strConnString

Set ADOCatalog.ActiveConnection = ADODBConnection


For Each ADOTable In ADOCatalog.Tables

    strSheetName = ADOTable.Name

    strSheetName = Replace(strSheetName, "'", "")

    strSheetName = Left(strSheetName, InStr(1, strSheetName, "$", 1) - 1)

    'Wscript.Echo strSheetName

    ArrSheetName(IndexArr)=strSheetName

    IndexArr=IndexArr+1

Next

ReDim Preserve ArrSheetName(IndexArr-1)

ADODBConnection.Close

Set ADOCatalog      = Nothing

Set ADOTable        = Nothing

Set ADODBConnection = Nothing


For Each ArrValue in ArrSheetName

    Wscript.Echo ArrValue

Next
```