# How do I get Table List in ODBC - Excel with nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel, list, odbc

I want to get Table List(Name List) in ODBC - excel width nodejs

In rdb, there is system table that include defined table list.
But in EXCEL, there is no one.

help, please

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to interface with ODBC from Node that I know of. If you're on Windows, you can try launching a WSH script in a child process:

```
child_process.exec('cscript.exe //nologo wsh_script.js', function (error, stdout, stderr) { ... });
```

where wsh_script.js would interface with Excel and return the results (perhaps in JSON) to Node via stdout. For instance, wsh_script.js might look something like:

```
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');
objExcel.Workbooks.Open(xlsFilePath);
var cellValue = objExcel.Cells(row, col).Value;
WScript.stdout.write(cellValue);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546345/how-to-read-a-spreadsheet-with-wsh) or [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx) for more info on how to interface with Excel/ODBC from WSH.